# Vectorize with Matlab Meshgrid in Chebfun

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use meshgrid in Matlab together with Chebfun to get rid of double for loops. I first define a quasi-matrix of N functions,

```
%Define functions of type Chebfun
N = 10; %number of functions
x = chebfun('x', [0 8]); %Domain
psi = [];
for i = 1:N 
psi = [psi sin(i.*pi.*x./8)];
end
```

A sample calculation would be to compute the double sum $\sum_{i,j=1}^10 psi(:,i).*psi(:,j)$. I can achieve this using two for loops in Matlab,

```
h = 0; 
for i = 1:N
for j = 1:N
h = h + psi(:,i).*psi(:,j);
end
end
```

I then tried to use meshgrid to vectorize in the following way:

```
[i j] = meshgrid(1:N,1:N);
h = psi(:,i).*psi(:,j);
```

I get the error "Column index must be a vector of integers". How can I overcome this issue so that I can get rid of my double for loops and make my code a bit more efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BTW, Chebfun is not part of native MATLAB and you have to download it in order to run your code: http://www.chebfun.org/.  However, that shouldn't affect how I answer your question.

Basically, `psi` is a `N` column matrix and it is your desire to add up products of all combinations of pairs of columns in `psi`.  You have the right idea with `meshgrid`, but what you should do instead is unroll the 2D matrix of coordinates for both `i` and `j` so that they're single vectors.  You'd then use this and create two `N^2` column matrices that is in such a way where each column corresponds to that exact column numbers specified from `i` and `j` sampled from `psi`.  You'd then do an element-wise multiplication between these two matrices and sum across all of the columns for each row.  BTW, I'm going to use `ii` and `jj` as variables from the output of `meshgrid` instead of `i` and `j`.  Those variables are reserved for the complex number in MATLAB and I don't want to overshadow those unintentionally.

Something like this:

```
%// Your code
N = 10; %number of functions
x = chebfun('x', [0 8]); %Domain
psi = [];
for i = 1:N 
psi = [psi sin(i.*pi.*x./8)];
end

%// New code
[ii,jj] = meshgrid(1:N, 1:N);

%// Create two matrices and sum
matrixA = psi(:, ii(:));
matrixB = psi(:, jj(:));
h = sum(matrixA.*matrixB, 2);
```

If you want to do away with the temporary variables, you can do it in one statement after calling `meshgrid`:

```
h = sum(psi(:, ii(:)).*psi(:, jj(:)), 2);
```

---

I don't have Chebfun installed, but we can verify that this calculates what we need with a simple example:

```
rng(123);
N = 10;
psi = randi(20, N, N);
```

Running this code with the above more efficient solution gives us:

```
>> h

h =

        8100
       17161
       10816
       12100
       14641
        9216
       10000
        8649
        9025
       11664
```

Also, running the above double `for` loop code also gives us:

```
>> h

h =

        8100
       17161
       10816
       12100
       14641
        9216
       10000
        8649
        9025
       11664
```

If you want to be absolutely sure, we can have both codes run with the outputs as separate variables, then check if they're equal:

```
%// Setup
rng(123);
N = 10;
psi = randi(20, N, N);

%// Old code
h = 0; 
for i = 1:N
    for j = 1:N
        h = h + psi(:,i).*psi(:,j);
    end
end 

%// New code
[ii,jj] = meshgrid(1:N, 1:N);
hnew = sum(psi(:, ii(:)).*psi(:, jj(:)), 2);

%// Check for equality
eql = isequal(h, hnew);
```

`eql` checks if both variables are equal, and we do get them as such:

```
>> eql

eql =

     1
```